# $\limsup_n |X_n|^{1/n}=1$ a.s iff $E[\log(1+|X_1|)$ is finite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Problem: Suppose $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d sequence such that $P[X_1=0]<1$. Show that $Z:=\limsup_n|X_n|^{1/n}=1\ a.s $ iff $E[\log(1+|X_1|)]<\infty$

In the direction from $\limsup_n |X_n|^{1/n}=1$ a.s to $E[\log(1+|X_1|)$ is finite i manage to get
that if I show $$\lim_n\prod^n_{j=1}E[|X_j|^{1/n}]<\infty$$ i finished. But I haven't managed to show it.

In the other direction i tried defining $E_n=\{|X_n|^{1/n}=1\}$ and using Borel-Cantelli but haven't managed to get much progress.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Perhaps you want to add the source of your problem (textbook, notes, etc) to asses the level of complexity you may be able to handle.

Comment: This problem is from my hw in probability theory so I dont know from where it is.
We just defined Expectation and learned Borel Cantelli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the conditions in the OP imply integrability of $|X_1|^{1/n}$. Here is a solution based on Borel-Cantelli's theorem and a little corollary of it:

> ***Lemma 1:*** Suppose $(Y_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d sequence of random variables.
> $$\frac{Y_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0\quad\text{a.s. iff}\quad E[|Y_1|]<\infty$$

A proof of Lemma 1 is given at the end of this posting.

---

### Solution to the OP:

Throughout the remaining of this posting, $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d. sequence.

#### Sufficiency:

First assume that
$E[\log(1+|X_1|)]<\infty$ and that $P[|X_1|=0]<1$. Lemma 1 implies that $C:=\big\{\frac{\log(1+|X_n|)}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0\big\}$ has full measure.

*Claim I:* $Z<\infty$ on $C$. If $Z(\omega)=\infty$, then there is sequence $n_k(\omega)$ such that $|X_{n_k(\omega)}|>2^{n_k(\omega)}$. Then $\limsup_k\frac{\log(1+|X_{n_k(\omega)}(\omega)|)}{n_k(\omega)}\geq\log2$ and so, $\omega\notin C$.

*Claim II:* $Z=1$ a.s. As  $P[|X_1|=0]<1$, there is $0<\varepsilon<1$ such that  $P[|X_1|>\varepsilon]>0$. Thus, $\sum_nP[|X_n|>\varepsilon]=\infty$, and by the reverse Borel Cantelli, $A=\{|X_n|>\varepsilon\,\text{i.o.}\}$ has full measure. For $\omega\in A\cap C$, there is a sequence $n_k$ (depending on $\omega$ such that
$$\frac{\log\varepsilon}{n_k}\leq \frac{\log|X_{n_k}|}{n_k}\leq\frac{\log(1+|X_{n_k}|)}{n_k}$$
Letting $k\rightarrow\infty$ yields $\lim_k|X_{n_k}|^{1/n_k}=1$. Hence $Z(\omega)=\limsup_n|X_n(\omega)|^{1/n}\geq1$.

Suppose $Z(\omega)>1$ and let $m_k(\omega)$ be a sequence such that $Z(\omega)=\lim_k |X_{m_k(\omega)}(\omega)|^{1/m_k(\omega)}$. Let $0<\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$ so that $Z-\varepsilon'>1$.
Then, for all $k$ large enough
$$\frac{\log(1+(Z(\omega)-\varepsilon')^{m_k(\omega)})}{m_k(\omega)}<\frac{\log(1+|X_{m_k(\omega)}(\omega)|)}{m_k(\omega)} $$
Letting $k\rightarrow\infty$ yields $0<\log(Z(\omega)-\varepsilon')\leq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Claims I and II imply that $Z=1$ a.s.

#### Necessity:

Now assume that $B=\{Z=1\}$ has full measure. This clearly implies that that $P[|X_1|=0]<1$. Let $\omega\in B$. Then, for $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that for $n\geq N$, $|X_n|<(1+\varepsilon)^n$. From
$$0\leq \frac{\log(1+|X_n|)}{n}\leq\frac{\log(1+(1+\varepsilon)^n)}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\log(1+\varepsilon)$$
it follows that $\lim_n\frac{\log(1+|X_n|)}{n}=0$. By Lemma 1, $E[\log(1+|X_1|)]<\infty$.

---

**Proof of Lemma I:** For any $\varepsilon>0$,
$$\varepsilon\sum_{n\geq1}P[|Y_1|>\varepsilon n]\leq E[|Y_1|]\leq \varepsilon\sum_{n\geq0}P[|Y_1|>n\varepsilon]$$
If $E[|Y_1|]<\infty$, then $\sum_nP[|Y_n|>\varepsilon n]=\sum_nP[|Y_1|>n\varepsilon]<\infty$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Borel-Cantelli's implies that
$P[|Y_n|>\varepsilon n,\,\text{i.o.}]=0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Let
$A_\varepsilon=\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon n\quad\text{i.o.}\}$. Then $P\big[\bigcap_mA^c_{1/m}\big]=1$. Notice that
$\bigcap_mA^c_{1/m}=\{\frac{Y_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0\}$.

Conversely, if $E[|Y_1|]=\infty$, then $\sum_nP[|Y_1|>n]=\sum_nP[|Y_n|>n]=\infty$. The reverse Borel-Cantelly theorem implies that $P[|Y_n|>n\,\text{i.o.}]=1$, which means that $P\big[\frac{Y_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0\big]=0$.

---

**Comment:** If in the assumptions in the OP $\limsup_n$ is replaced by $\lim_n$, that is  $\lim_n|X_n|^{1/n}=1$ a.s. and $P[|X_1|=0]<1$, then we have

$$\lim_n|X_n|^{1/n}=1\quad\text{a.s.}\qquad\text{iff}\qquad E[|\log(|X_1|)|]<\infty$$